# How to read JSON data from same json for tree layout insteadof reading from other .JSON file?

Tags: d3.js

how to read JSON data from same .js file instead of reading it from other .JSON file currently I am using  :

```
d3.json("network.json", function(error, treeData){
   // tree layout logic goes here

}
```

instead of this can we read data from same js file ang how to use it to build tree layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**:

1.you can  assign the JSON data to variable name then You can build the tree layout

2.use one function to get the `JSON` data

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/r7xRy/2/) for 1 solution

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/xGKfu/)** for 2 solution

```
    var root = getData(),
    nodes = cluster.nodes(root),
    links = cluster.links(nodes);
```