# using d3.json method with Json object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am generating an zoomable chart by using d3.js.

chart data is being received as json object. how to change the following code to work with JSON object

```
d3.json("mydata.json", function(json) {
//TODO: 
});
```

instead of file name "msdata.json" I want to use Json object. please help me how to do this.

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by "JSON object", because [there is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Maybe you mean an object (`var obj = {foo: 'bar'};`) or JSON as a string (`var json = '{"foo": "bar"}';`) ?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834760/how-to-read-json-data-from-same-json-for-tree-layout-insteadof-reading-from-othe/20835211#20835211

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a JSON *string* (there's no such thing as JSON object) in the script, you can remove your `d3.json` request and use `JSON.parse` to convert the JSON string to an object (usually it's an array) like so:

```
var data = JSON.parse(yourJSONString);
```

Then you can use it to compute data joins or whatever you want to do with it in d3:

```
someSelection.data(data).enter()... // etc.
```